# How to use predefined text in JSF in HTML tag attribute?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

In my messages.properties I have:

```
page.title=Page Title
```

and then I use it like this:

```
<title>        
  <ui:insert name="pageTitle">
    <h:outputText value="#{messages['page.title']}" escape="false"/>
  </ui:insert>
</title>
```

Is there some way how can i use it also in title attribute of:

```
    <link rel="search" title="HERE" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="search_plugin_new.xml" />
```

If not what's the best practice please?
Thank you

Comment: So you haven't even just tried it?

Comment: Hi @BalusC

of course I did =)

`Error Parsing /templates/base1.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 30] The value of attribute "title" associated with an element type "link" must not contain the '<' character.`

Comment: You seem to have placed whole `<h:outputText>` in `title` attribute. This indeed doesn't make sense. See duplicate for correct approach.

Comment: Sorry for silly question but I'm just beginning with JSF - how can I access messages via EL? TIA

Comment: Like this?:

     `<link rel="search" title="#{messages['page.title']}" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="search_plugin_new.xml" />`

Comment: Just for the records:

method in above comment works just fine

Thank you for nudge @BalusC